# Generating code with babel-plugin-codegen: Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, code-generation, babel-plugin

I'm trying to generate a component during the build based on some params using `babel-plugin-codegen` (https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-codegen). I've spent hours and this is where I'm at now: it looks like my component is successfully generated through babel-cli, but not during build-time. I get an error: `Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'`.

Here is my repo: https://github.com/abimatov/babel-macro-demo

Here are my detailed steps:

1. I created a new Next.js project (https://nextjs.org/docs): `npx create-next-app@latest`
2. Started the application: `npm run dev`
3. Ran `npm i @babel/core --save-dev`, `npm i @babel/cli --save-dev`, `npm i babel-plugin-macros --save-dev`, `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-preval`, `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-codegen`
4. Created a `.babelrc` file with the following contents:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": ["macros", "preval", "codegen"]
}
```

5. My `pages/index.js` looks something like this:

```
import codegen from 'babel-plugin-codegen';


export default function Home() {
  const CodegenComponent = codegen.require('../components/codegenDemo');
  return <>
    <CodegenComponent />
  </>;
}
```

6. My `codegenDemo.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = (input) => `<div>${input}</div>`;
```

7. I run `npx babel .\pages\index.js` and the output looks right-ish to me:

```
"use strict";

var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports["default"] = Home;
var _react = _interopRequireDefault(require("react"));
var _babelPluginCodegen = _interopRequireDefault(require("babel-plugin-codegen"));
var __jsx = _react["default"].createElement;
function Home() {
  var CodegenComponent = __jsx("div", null, "undefined");
  return __jsx(_react["default"].Fragment, null, __jsx(CodegenComponent, null));
}
```

8. I run `npm run dev` and go to `localhost:3000`

Expected result: I should see the CodegenComponent rendered (basically, just `<div></div>`).

Actual result: An error that `Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

`codegenDemo.js`:

```
module.exports = (input) => `const CodegenComponent = () => <div>${input}</div>`;
```

`pages/index.js`:

```
import /* codegen(123) */ '../components/codegenDemo';
export default function Home() {
  return <>
    <CodegenComponent />
  </>;
}
```